# finding out the bandwidth of m(t)*m(t) if the bandwidth of m(t) is a known quantity

Tags: modulation, bandwidth, fourier, convolution

m(t)*m(t) in time domain is equivalent to the convolution of m(w) and m(w) in frequency domain.Thus if the bandwidth of m(t) is a known quantity then how is the bandwidth of m(t)*m(t) is determined?

Comment: Hint. What is the highest frequency component of sin(t) * sin(t)?

Comment: Do you understand what "convolution" means? Saying that you know the "bandwidth" of a signal means that you know some general facts about \$m(\omega)\$, even if you don't know its precise definition.

Answer (score 2):

Your bandwidth will double. You can derive this using trig identities:

[image]

DC and 2*theta components will form unless you filter them out.
I ran a quick simulation in MATLAB to confirm. F(m(t)) on the top-left, F(m(t)*m(t)) on top-right. Bottom-left is the the top-left zoomed in, and vice verse.

[image]
[image]
conclusions:

1. m(t) has a passband from 4kHz to 6kHz
2. m(t)*m(t) has twice the bandwidth, and massive DC componets

Side note, not related to your question:

This property is actually exploited in QPSK demodulation. Here the double frequency is eliminated almost perfectly by mathematically performing something called "integrate-and-dump". (Or you can always just use a low pass filter too). Any good communications textbook will describe this in detail.